# Ubuntu 14.04 - view at all the windows

Tags: windows, promotion

See video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FowVnfIbd4

This works when I have one workspace. I use more workspaces and then it does not work.
How can I have a look at all the windows in all workspaces in a manner as shown in the video. Ubuntu 11.10 that I used had this option. Now I have Ubuntu 14.04. Please help me.

Thank you

Milos